# GUI won't open and not sure how to make variables

Tags: python

I'm getting an error "No objects to concatenate" on line 50: newtime = yf.download(ticker_info, start = startdate_info, end = enddate_info) and the program closes before the user interface can open. I'm just trying to list the Entries as strings to use in the bottom function.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("450x550")

startdate = StringVar()
start_date = Label(text = "Enter start date in YYYY-MM-DD format: ")
start_date.place(x = 15, y = 70)
startdate_entry = Entry(textvariable = startdate, width = "30")
startdate_entry.place(x = 15, y = 120)

enddate = StringVar()
end_date = Label(text = "Enter end date in YYYY-MM-DD format: ")
end_date.place(x = 15, y = 170)
enddate_entry = Entry(textvariable = enddate, width = "30")
enddate_entry.place(x = 15, y = 220)

tickerE = StringVar()
ticker_label = Label(text = "Ticker symbol:  ")
ticker_label.place(x = 15, y = 270)
ticker = Entry(textvariable = tickerE, width = "30")
ticker.place(x = 15, y = 320)

inspectE = StringVar()
inspect_label = Label(text = "What would you like to analyze  ")
inspect_label.place(x = 15, y = 270)
inspect_label = Label(text = "(Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume)? ")
inspect_label.place(x = 15, y = 320)
inspect = Entry(textvariable = inspectE, width = "30")
inspect.place(x = 15, y = 370)

def save_info():
    startdate_info = startdate.get()
    enddate_info = enddate.get()
    ticker_info = tickerE.get()
    inspect_info = inspectE.get()
    return ticker_info, inspect_info, startdate_info, enddate_info

search = Button(screen,text = "Search", width = "30", height = "2", command = save_info, bg = "grey")
search.place(x = 14, y = 410)
ticker_info, inspect_info, startdate_info, enddate_info = save_info()

newtime = yf.download(ticker_info, start = startdate_info, end = enddate_info)
print(newtime)
def adjusted_close(ticker_info, newtime):
    newtime[inspect_info].plot()
    plt.xlabel("Date")
    plt.ylabel(inspect_info)
    plt.title(ticker_info + " " + inspect_info + " "  + "Data")
    plt.show()
adjusted_close(ticker, newtime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some modifications to you code and please use the below code.

Main thing which was missed in your code was screen.mainloop() this is the one which starts your GUI.

Compare it with your code and see the changes.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("450x600")

startdate = StringVar()
start_date = Label(text = "Enter start date in YYYY-MM-DD format: ")
start_date.place(x = 15, y = 70)
startdate_entry = Entry(textvariable = startdate, width = "30")
startdate_entry.place(x = 15, y = 120)
print("hllo")
enddate = StringVar()
end_date = Label(text = "Enter end date in YYYY-MM-DD format: ")
end_date.place(x = 15, y = 170)
enddate_entry = Entry(textvariable = enddate, width = "30")
enddate_entry.place(x = 15, y = 220)

tickerE = StringVar()
ticker_label = Label(text = "Ticker symbol:  ")
ticker_label.place(x = 15, y = 270)
ticker = Entry(textvariable = tickerE, width = "30")
ticker.place(x = 15, y = 320)

inspectE = StringVar()
inspect_label = Label(text = "What would you like to analyze  ")
inspect_label.place(x = 15, y = 370)
inspect_label = Label(text = "(Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume)? ")
inspect_label.place(x = 15, y = 420)
inspect = Entry(textvariable = inspectE, width = "30")
inspect.place(x = 15, y = 470)



def adjusted_close(ticker_info, newtime,info):
    print(info)
    newtime[info].plot()
    plt.xlabel("Date")
    plt.ylabel(info)
    plt.title(ticker_info + " " + info + " "  + "Data")
    plt.show()

    #SPY APPL
def save_info():
    startdate_info = startdate.get()
    enddate_info = enddate.get()
    ticker_info = tickerE.get()
    inspect_info = inspectE.get()
    print(inspect_info)
    newtime = yf.download(ticker_info, start = startdate_info, end = enddate_info,group_by= 'Ticker')
    print(newtime)
    # calling this after the button is clicked
    adjusted_close(ticker_info,newtime,inspect_info)


search = Button(screen,text = "Search", width = "30", height = "2", command = save_info, bg = "grey")
search.place(x = 14, y = 520)

#this was missed code hence we did not get a pop up
screen.mainloop()
```

See below it worked for me!

[image: Working for me]

Kindly let me know if you need more help!

Comment: Welcome! Happy that it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use get_data_yahoo() when you are using start and end date.

If you see the below link https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/
for yf.download they are asking us to use periods instead of start and end.

## use "period" instead of start/end

```
    # valid periods: 1d,5d,1mo,3mo,6mo,1y,2y,5y,10y,ytd,max
    # (optional, default is '1mo')
```

If you want to use start and end date try the following.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override() # <== that's all it takes :-)

# download dataframe
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("SPY", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")
```

Please check and let me know if this help or else we can dig more on this code. Thanks!

Comment: It downloads all the data I need when I use input instead of an Entry field to assign start date, end date, ticker and inspect. So it downloads the data if I give it the fields through input not Entry. Also I'm not using pandas_datareader. Still have the problem  "No objects to concatenate" on line 50

Comment: Yes as far as I saw the documentation , yf.download() dosent give you option to give start and end dates. So if you want to give start and end date then you need to with get_data_yahoo() by using pandas. Kindly let me know if my understanding needs correction about the yf.download(). Thanks!

Comment: import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download("SPY AAPL", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30") This is the documentation. I'm using matplotlib for analysis. So a user should get a GUI pop up asking for these entries and also inspect. But there is a problem with line 50. It's like it wont put the strings entered by users in the gui into those fields.

Comment: ok I think its about concatenation. then can you try this way and see if it works for you.
data = yf.download("SPY AAPL", start='"'+startdate_info+'"',end='"'+enddate_info+'"')

Before you try this can you check your date format by printing the dates using 
print(startdate_info)

Comment: This still doesn't solve the issue. To start, the GUI doesn't open. It should open and ask for the entries. It doesn't even open for the user to type the date in the GUI.

Comment: Adding another answer for this!